# Primary sources on Medieval Christian depictions of non-Christians (in English)

Tags: middle-ages, europe, christianity, vikings

I'm a history student and I'm looking for primary sources in English (not Latin) that could help me with my research. I'm trying to find primary sources preferably written by Christian monks about the Vikings, (pagan) Slavs, Magyars, and the invasion of Iberia. I am trying to find similarities between the way different non-Christian groups were portrayed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One example which talks about Vikings (at some length) is the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle. Several manuscripts survive, written in Old English (e.g. the [first page of the Peterborough Chronicle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Peterborough.Chronicle.firstpage.jpg))

Comment: You might have some real fun with this, there are a lot of excellent sources. In particular, medieval Iceland had a whole literary genre in which christian monks wrote about their pagan ancestors. Some of these sagas deal explicitly with religious themes. The saga of Thorvald Farfarer is about an early christian convert, the saga of Hrafnkel Freysgodi is about an unusually devoted pagan, Njal's saga describes the conversion of Iceland, Laxdæla saga an encounter between pagan icelanders and the christian King Olaf, Heimskringla has a nice account of a miracle worker called Poppo.

Comment: Oh, and a lot of the sagas feature witchcraft, which would certainly fall under christians describing pagans. There's too many examples to list, but the most obvious source would be the conflict between Egil and Gunnlaug in Egil's saga.

Comment: Do you want primary sources originally in (Old) English, or do you accept translations as well?

Comment: ^ (I made a typo on my second comment, I meant *Gunnhild*.)